# GPU-accelerated hardware simulation?

Tags: cuda, simulation, opencl, hardware-acceleration

I am investigating if GPGPUs could be used for accelerating simulation of hardware.
My reasoning is this: As hardware by nature is very parallel, why simulate on highly sequential CPUs?

GPUs would be excellent for this, if not for their restrictive style of programming: You have a single kernel running, etc.

I have little experience with GPGPU-programming, but is it possible to use events or queues in OpenCL / CUDA?

Edit: By hardware simulation I don't mean emulation, but bit-accurate behavorial simulation (as in VHDL behavioral simulation).

Comment: My gut says discrete event simulation is not a good fit for GPUs. Too much control, not enough arithmetic intensity, possibly too irregular. I'd be interested for somebody to prove this intuition wrong... come to think of it, maybe I recall skimming a paper on just this. I'll consult notes and let you know what turns up.

Comment: @Patrick87, my thoughts exactly. A link to a paper would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any approaches regarding VHDL simulation on GPUs (or a general scheme to map discrete-event simulations), but there *are* certain application areas where discrete-event simulation is typically applied and which *can* be simulated efficiently on GPUs (e.g. transportation networks, as in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/PADS.2009.22) or [this one](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/HPCSIM.2009.5192895), or stochastic simulation of chemical systems, as done in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/PDMC-HiBi.2010.18)).

Is it possible to re-formulate the problem in a way that makes a discrete time-stepped simulator feasible? In this case, simulation on a GPU should be much simpler (and still faster, even if it seems wasteful because the time steps have to be sufficiently small - see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SIMUL.2009.36) on the GPU-based simulation of cellular automata, for example).

Note, however, that this is still most likely **a non-trivial (research) problem**, and the reason why there is no general scheme (yet) is what you already assumed: implementing an event queue on a GPU is difficult, and most simulation approaches on GPUs gain speed-up due to *clever memory layout* and *application-specific* optimizations and problem modifications.

Comment: Thanks. Paper #2 might be of use.

Comment: I also found http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-05192010-051432/unrestricted/Nanjundappa_M_T_2010.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is outside my area of expertise, but it seems that while the following paper discusses gate-level simulation rather than behavioral simulation, it may contain some useful ideas:

Debapriya Chatterjee, Andrew Deorio, Valeria Bertacco.
Gate-Level Simulation with GPU Computing
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~valeria/research/publications/TODAES0611.pdf

Comment: Page not found.

Comment: @Goldname I fixed the link rot, please try again.